# Superping doesn't seem to work with soft returns

Tags: bug, chat

I am seeing something weird in chat.  If I use the @@ syntax in chat to superping someone, the @@uid gets replaced with the username when I send the message.  If I use the @@ syntax and have soft returns in the message (ie, shift-returns), the @@uid stays numeric and I don't think the superping is actually going out.

Comment: That's perhaps not a bug; soft returns disable all markdown processing in a post as well, with the exception of indentation to make something a codeblock (and then the whole block would have to be indented).